# Korean hangul with voiced, unvoiced and aspirated or not aspirated

Tags: pronunciation, hangul, resources, spoken-korean

Does anyone know where can I find Korean alphabet which tells if a vowel or consonant is voiced or unvoiced, aspirated or not?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can tell you right now.

(Always) Voiced: all vowels, ㄴ, ㅁ, ㅇ(final), ㄹ

(Conditionally) Voiceless: ㄱ, ㄲ, ㄷ, ㄸ, ㅂ, ㅃ, ㅅ, ㅆ, ㅈ, ㅉ, ㅊ, ㅋ, ㅌ, ㅍ, ㅎ

(Strongly) Aspirated: ㅋ, ㅌ, ㅍ, ㅅ, ㅊ, ㅎ

Not (strongly) aspirated: ㄱ, ㄷ, ㅂ, ㅈ

Not aspirated: ㄲ, ㄸ, ㅃ, ㅆ, ㅉ

Note that Korean doesn't really phonemically contrast voicing, so it's not weird if a voiced consonant comes out voiceless, or vice versa. It happens all the time.

Asking if a Korean stop consonant is voiced or not is akin to asking if English /p/ is aspirated or not. It is sometimes, and it is sometimes not. For example, "pin" is usually aspirated, but "spin" is usually not. So is English /p/ aspirated? Yes and no. Is Korean ㅂ voiced? Yes and no.

Refer to the wikipedia for more info about [Korean phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_phonology).

Comment: Thank you very much. I am aslo having problem with 요 sound. I pronounced it as "jo" sound but my Korean friend said that it is wrong. Could you explain it more?

Comment: @anhnha I assume you're a native English speaker. If my assumption is correct, chances are you're pronouncing ㅗ as English /oʊ/("boat" vowel) which is close to [əʊ] actually. Korean /o/ is a monophthong, and your tongue and lips should not move while articulating the vowel.

Comment: Thanks. I am a Vietnamese. I don't think that I have problem with /o/ sound but /y/ sound/. In IPA the /y/ sound is same as /j/ but my friend in Korean /y/ in yo is not as /j/. Sorry that I didn't express myself clearly.

Comment: Okay, you should only put IPA in slashes, otherwise it gets confusing because in IPA /j/ and /y/ are different. If you need to refer to English orthography, use angle brackets <y> or just quotes "y". Now, ㅛ /jo/ definitely contains /j/, the "y" sound in "yes". Maybe your friend just doesn't understand IPA and the /j/ sound.

Comment: @anhnha If you speak Vietnamese natively, perhaps your 요 has too much diphthongisation anyway, and is probably too open. E.g. Vietnamese _cô_ in many people's speech is pronounced [kɔo̯], which is different from 고 [ko ~ ku], a lot tighter. In fact, Vietnamese _cô_ may sound more like 거 to Korean ears.

Comment: Thanks. I had problem with /j/ sound. Is it same as /i/ in that case?

Comment: @anhnha It is similar to /i/, except /j/ is an approximant version of the vowel /i/. /j/ is to /i/ as /w/ is to /u/.

Comment: This was useful (see answer by geisendorf). https://www.reddit.com/r/Korean/comments/3qg5dz/question_about_consonants_in_korean_%E3%85%88%E3%85%8A_%E3%84%B7%E3%85%8C_%E3%85%82%E3%85%8D/